# Error while using MysqlDataAdapter

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I was following a tutorial on the internet ( [link](http://www.authorcode.com/image-gallery-in-vb-net/) ) to create a a picture gallery. I got it all working, but i changed:

```
Private Sub CreateGallery()
        i = 0
        RemoveControls()
        If Directorypath IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Directorypath)
            Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.jpg").Concat(di.GetFiles("*.bmp")).Concat(di.GetFiles("*.png")).Concat(di.GetFiles("*.gif")).ToArray
            Dim dra As IO.FileInfo
            For Each dra In diar1
                DrawPictureBox(dra.FullName, dra.Name)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

to:

```
Private Sub CreateGallery()
        Dim table = New DataTable
        Using Connection = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=barra;Database=pap")
            Using da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM filme", Connection)
                da.Fill(table)
            End Using
        End Using
        i = 0
        RemoveControls()
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            Try
                Dim bytes() As Byte
                bytes = (row("imagem"))
                Dim memStream As New MemoryStream(bytes)
                DrawPictureBox(memStream, row("titulo"))
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub
```

It was working fine, the way i wanted, when i tried to do it on another project it gives me an error on 'MySqlDataAdapter':

```
Using da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM filme", Connection)
```

the erros says : Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments

I tried almost everything i can't make it work.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be "UserID=root" and not "User Id=root"?  I think that space is causing a problem.  To me it looks like an error with MySqlConnection so when you go to pass Connection into the method it's complaining about not being able to find a version of New that works with your arguments.

Comment: Well, pay attention to Intellisense then.  If you enter `Using da = New MySqlDataAdapter(` into the code window then Intellisense will tell you what options you have.  Don't ignore the information at your fingertips.

Comment: @Dresden I have the code just like that in another project and it work's great. I copied to to my newer project and it doesn't work.

Comment: @jmcilhinney in the Intellisense it says:MySqlDataAdapter(selectedCommandText as string, connection as MysqlConnection)

Comment: I mean your error is saying one of your arguments for MySqlDataAdapter is not compatible with the overloaded method.  It's either the string or the MySqlConnection object and I doubt it's the string.  Did you copy and paste from one vb.net project to another?

Comment: @Dresden yeah i copied it, but i already try to do it by hand and its always showing that error, it's strange because on the other project its everything the same and it works

Comment: I fixed it, i had a file on the project called Mysqlconnection.vb or mysqlconnector.vb i just deleted it and the error disappeared!

Answer (score 0):

convert your function as class and call :

```
dim new_creator as yourclass
```

...

Comment: Actually the problem was when I copied the code from my older project to the new, visual studio created a file on the project called i think "Mysqlconnection.vb" and that was messing my code, when i deleted the file it came back to normal

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
   Private Sub CreateGallery()
    Dim table As New DataTable
    Dim Conn As New SqlConnection
    Conn = New SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=<DataBase>;User ID=sa;password=<password>;Data Source=<ServerName>"")
    Dim com As String = ""
    com = "SELECT * FROM Table "
    Dim getComm As New SqlDataAdapter(com, Conn)
    getComm.Fill(table)
    i = 0
    RemoveControls()
    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
        Dim bytes() As Byte
        bytes = (row("Imagee"))
        Dim memStream As New MemoryStream(bytes)
        DrawPictureBox(memStream, row("Bro_Path"))
    End Sub
```

and change ByVal _filename As MemoryStream,

```
    Private Sub DrawPictureBox(ByVal _filename As MemoryStream, ByVal _displayname As String)
```